# How to create a file with unique id using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to create file into specified directory with unique id's, Any idea what is implemented wrong in below code. 
Two things here ..

1- Its not generating files into specific directory `records` , how can i create file into specific directory ?

2- Using node uuid , How can i create unique id's for each file that is being generated ?

logs.js

```
var uuid = require('node-uuid');
var fs = require('fs');
var path = './app/records'
var filename = 'server' + uuid.v4() + '.txt'
var userLogs = function (data) {
    fs.writeFile(path,filename,data,function () {
        console.log(filename);
    });
    console.log('userLogs', data);
};
module.exports = userLogs;
```

output filenames have same id's

```
userLogs [ 'Test Log  messages' ]
server7695c20a-5ddf-4d67-a437-3d0b9d354ed1.txt
userLogs [ 'Test Log  messages' ]
server7695c20a-5ddf-4d67-a437-3d0b9d354ed1.txt
info: Test Log  messages
from console Test Log  messages
userLogs [ 'Test Log  messages', 'Test Log  messages' ]
server7695c20a-5ddf-4d67-a437-3d0b9d354ed1.txt
```

Comment: You are only generating a uuid once. you generate it and assign it to 'var filename' so it will always be the same. You can use a 'for' loop to generate new uuid and write to file. Also can you show your folder directories or folder tree?

Comment: my directories > app> records  where i am trying to write a file

Comment: yes but what is the full directory of your project. like where is logs.js?

Comment: project > app > records > logs.js

Comment: So you want to save the .txt to the same location that logs.js is at?

Comment: for now yes i want to use records directory

Comment: fs.writeFile(filename, data, [encoding], callback). This is from their doucmentation, i think maybe you are passing wrong params into writeFile function. Get rid of the path parameter and see what happens

Comment: fs.writeFile('message.txt', 'Hello Node.js', (err) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('It\'s saved!');
});

Comment: without path its creating a file but not into records, its creating at root of project folder

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html        Documentation for 'fs'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var path = '/absolute/path/to/records'
var userLogs = function (data) {
var filename = 'server' + uuid.v4() + '.txt';
    fs.writeFile(path,filename,data,function () {
        console.log(filename);
    });
    console.log('userLogs', data);
};
```

Declare filename as a local variable inside the userLogs function. This way, each time it is called, the uuid function is called again.

Comment: That resolved one issue of uuid, but its still not creating a file in 'records' directory.